# SSRS and Health Monitoring

Tags: reporting-services, health-monitoring

Has anyone implemented ASP.NET Health Monitoring with SSRS? I need a better solution for error notification, then SSRS currently have. Any help would be great.

Thank You,

Comment: What kind of error notification are you looking for?  Web-application level failures or failures when the reports are run?  What version of SSRS are you running?

Comment: I'm running SSRS 2008, the errors that I'm receiving are from my data driven subscriptions. It says that its ran and x number of items has been processed, but there were errors. I can look atlog at the logs, but I would like have a way to be notified when an error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You can have another subscribed report for this, which actually queries the log (SSRS system tables)  and  pull the information from there , let's say on hourly basis.